# Form validation play framework 2.0

Tags: java, playframework, validation, illegalstateexception

I'm following the tutorial at http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0/JavaForms

I've created a class LoginForm.java (Instead of User.class from the example. Not a class for persisting, just a form values holder)

```
package domain;

import static play.data.validation.Constraints.*;

public class LoginForm {

        @Required
        public String email;
        public String password;

}
```

And in my controller i do (as the example), but i set the values to empty Strings to try the @Required annotation.

```
Form<LoginForm> loginForm = form(LoginForm.class);
Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap();
anyData.put("email", "");
anyData.put("password", "");

//Faking a post
LoginForm postedLoginForm = loginForm.bind(anyData).get();

if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
  //Just for this test task, should have another error handling..
  return ok("@Required annotation kicked in..");
} else {
  return ok("Got form values, email: " + postedLoginForm.email + " password: " + postedLoginForm.password);
}
```

But at:

```
LoginForm postedLoginForm = loginForm.bind(anyData).get();
```

I get an Execution exception [[IllegalStateException: No value]]

So it never checks/comes to

```
if(loginForm.hasErrors())
```

Does anyone know why this is? If i set the values as the example:

```
Map<String,String> anyData = new HashMap();
anyData.put("email", "bob@gmail.com");
anyData.put("password", "secret");
```

Everything works and i retrieve the LoginForm object with the correct values.
Am i supposed to catch the Exception? Shouldn't play take care of that and set loginForm.hasErrors = true?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: It seems like the IllegalStateException is coming from `bind`. Maybe that method doesn't allow you to `bind` or `get` when your map has no data.

Comment: I see but the same goes for a real post when I use loginForm.bindFromRequest().get(), which binds data from the request. How would one validate if the user didn't put any data in the form fields? Without having to write an own validate method?

Comment: But you said the real post works, in which you have no empty values in your map.

Comment: Sorry, the real post didn't work either. With empty input fields values.

Comment: So the post with a populated email and password didn't work? You said it work work like expected in your post.

Comment: Yeah the real/fake post with populated fields works. Then the required annotation doesn't bother. But if the email field is empty (which has the @Required annotation). The exception is thrown. Shouldn't loginForm.hasErrors() be true? Instead of a thrown exception?

Comment: That's what I was saying earlier about it might be with `bind` or `get` and the fact that it is empty. You should start by searching there.

Comment: But what's the purpose of the @Required annotation then?

Comment: Shouldn't it check if the the field has a value. Otherwise set the hasErrors to true?

Answer (score 25):

This is expected behavior.

Note that you must use .get() on form After check for errors.

```
LoginForm preLoginForm = loginForm.bind(anyData);

if(loginForm.hasErrors()) {
    //Just for this test task, should have another error handling..
    return ok("@Required annotation kicked in..");
}
LoginForm postedLoginForm = preLoginForm.get();
// ... Now use postedLoginForm
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a bug with Play 2.0 framework. I was able to replicate the same problem locally.

I opened a ticket https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/313 in case you want to follow up.

Comment: issue was closed as invalid - this is expected behaviour